# Add items to layer script Adobe Illustrator

Tags: javascript, api, adobe, adobe-illustrator

This may be a something I skipped over in my search, but can anyone show me how to add an item to a layer using a JavaScript Adobe Illustrator script?

Also, are there any good resources for learning how to write scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: This link should help you out... https://illustrator-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/jsobjref/Layers/

Comment: Hi @dalelandry thanks for the link. I had found it previously and it specifies how to add a layer to a document but not an object to a layer. Do you know how I could do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of object you want to add, but
For example, add the following for a text area.

```
var rect = layer.pathItems.rectangle(500, 200, 200, 100);
var txtFrame = layer.textFrames.areaText(rect);
```